# Generate UUID for each group in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to generate UUID for each group created from below data in neo4j.
So that I can export each group data separately.

```
p1,p2
nishant,anish
anish,jose
nishant,jose
xiaoyi,neil
xiaoyi,menish
pavan,ankur
```

```
load csv with headers
from 'file:///hd.csv' as line
merge (per1:person1{person1:line.p1})
merge (per2:person1{person1:line.p2})
create (per1)-[:knows]->(per2)
```

Comment: do you meant you want the same uuid on each node in a pair?

Comment: Above data will create 3 different clusters(groups), my requirement is to give unique id to these 3 groups.

Comment: It is not clear where you want to store the UUID.

Comment: I want to export the data in csv as below.
`nishant,anish,123
anish,jose,123
nishant,jose,123
xiaoyi,neil,756
xiaoyi,menish,756
pavan,ankur,825`

Comment: 1. Do you actually want to "import" the CSV data into neo4j? 2. Are you trying to assign the same unique UUID value to all `person1` nodes in the same "cluster"? If so, what is the technical definition of "cluster" that you want to use?

Comment: Yes, I will be loading above csv file into neo4j. It would create 3 different graphs/clusters/groups in the same database something like below.

nishant,anish,jose
neil,xiaoyi,menish
pavan,ankur

My requirement is to give unique id to these 3 groups like below.

nishant,anish,jose,123
neil,xiaoyi,menish,756
pavan,ankur,825

Answer (score 2):

ok, I made an attempt at something that might satisfy you. Here goes...

The basic premise is if a `group_uuid` has already been set in a pair of `person1` nodes then use it. If not then generate a new one and set it where it has not been set.

```
// same as above
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///hd.csv' as line
MERGE (per1:person1 {person1: line.p1})
MERGE (per2:person1 {person1: line.p2})
CREATE (per1)-[:knows]->(per2)

// determine which uuid value to use
// if per1 or per2 already has a uuid use it
// otherwise use apoc to generate one
WITH per1, per2,
CASE
  WHEN per1.group_uuid IS NOT NULL THEN per1.group_uuid 
  WHEN per2.group_uuid IS NOT NULL THEN per2.group_uuid
  ELSE apoc.create.uuid()
END AS uuid_to_use

// if per1 does not have a uuid set then set it
FOREACH (
  x in CASE WHEN NOT exists(per1.uuid) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | SET per1.group_uuid = uuid_to_use
)

// if per2 does not have a uuid set then set it
FOREACH (
  x in CASE WHEN NOT exists(per2.uuid) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | SET per2.group_uuid = uuid_to_use
)
```

Comment: is Neo4j  also assign a default group id to each graph?

Comment: How to apply the same logic while using neo4j import tool?

Comment: you can create it after you have loaded your data OR you would need to pre-process the data and create one for each group

Comment: Actually I have 500 millions records in same format. I was trying "load csv " command to load, it got failed(memory issue) then i used "neo4j import tool" cli command to load data and make relationships. Now i want to generate UUID for each group in optimized way.